# How to re render only one element on state change React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I have this function that makes this button have a rainbow background by incrementing red, green, blue on the state. So the state is constantly updating. When it does, I only need this one button in my render() to rerender. Everything else can stay the same. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code. It could be that you simply need something like [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), or it could be that you need a more complex solution. Please make sure your question includes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: React will only update the DOM elements that actually changed. If your `render()` function renders multiple other elements that do not depend on your state changes they will not be changed. React uses a shadow DOM to create a diff from what gets rendered and only do the necessary updates.